# when i run magento using xampp it shows Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality:

Tags: php, xampp

*Fatal error:*
 **Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in**

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php on line 81 in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'The each() func...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 81, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php(81): each(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory.php(156): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magent in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php on line 61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to documentation Magento has provided through their [DevDocs Magento 2.2.x technology stack requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

In addition to listing compatible versions of PHP that Magento2 can handle, PHP configuration settings that are recommended or required are listed too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check php version is compatible with you magento version.

[Check php and magento version](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is not officially compatible with PHP 7.2.

check here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on localhost, issue has been resolved now

PHP VERSION ISSUE : change 7.2.4 to 7.1.6

You can also refer this below guide:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html